# How to insert data with my node endpoint from an angular component?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, mongodb, mongoose

I'm very new to angular and I'm trying to design a simple web. I have my backend ready in node.js. Right now I have an endpoint created where I insert data into my database. It's basically an endpoint to create posts.

This is my mongoose schema:

```
const trackingPostSchema = new Schema({
    uuid: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
      },
    post: [{
        foodUuid: String,
        pictureUrl: String,
        foodName: String,
        description: String,
        calories: Number,
        eatenAt: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now()
        },
        mealTime: String, //breakfast, lunch, dinner
    }],
  });
```

and I'm trying to insert the data with this component:

```
<nz-card style="width:300px;" nzTitle="Track what you ate today!">

  <div class="content">

    <input nz-input placeholder="Food Name" [(ngModel)]="foodName" style="max-width: 100px; min-width: 100px;" class="data"/>

    <input nz-input placeholder="Food Description" [(ngModel)]="description" style="max-width: 200px; min-width: 100px;" class="data"/>

    <label for="calories" style="margin-left: 10px">Calories: </label>
    <nz-input-number [(ngModel)]="calories" [nzMin]="1" [nzMax]="10000" [nzStep]="1" style="min-width: 100px;" class="data" id="calories"></nz-input-number>

    <nz-select
        style="width: 100px;"
        nzShowSearch
        nzAllowClear
        nzPlaceHolder="Select a meal time"
        [(ngModel)]="mealTime"
        class="data"
      >
        <nz-option nzLabel="Breakfast" nzValue="Breakfast"></nz-option>
        <nz-option nzLabel="Lunch" nzValue="Lunch"></nz-option>
        <nz-option nzLabel="Dinner" nzValue="Dinner"></nz-option>
    </nz-select>

    <button nz-button nzType="primary" class="data">Post</button>

  </div>

</nz-card>
```

I know it is a broad question, but what would be the steps I'd need to follow to send this data to my backend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send the data to the backend with a simple http request. You need to attack a click handler to your `POST` button which will call a function. This function can send the values to the backend as an object.

In component.html file, do this: 
`<button nz-button nzType="primary" (click)="sendDataToBackend()" class="data">Post</button>`

In the component.ts file, do this:

`import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';`

```
httpOptions = {
headers: new HttpHeaders({
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  //'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + YOUR_AUTHENTICATION_TOKEN // Enable this if using authentication
})
};
```

In your class in component.ts file, create a function sendDataToBackend:

```
sendDataToBackend(){
this.http.post(YOUR_ENDPOINT,{foodName, description,calories,mealTime} , 
this.httpOptions).toPromise().then((res) => console.log(res));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you might need Rest APIs to communicate from front-end to back-end.

https://www.restapitutorial.com/

You need to create a model that defines the structure of your database schema and access the same via Rest APIs to do Create/Read/Update/Delete (CRUD) operations on your database schema.

There are many ways to structurally create Rest APIs for project needs. Its based on your project Infrastructure.

1) If you have a back-end modules with APIs defined as a separate project,

You can write a middleware component that imports HTTP module of angular with a function http.Post.

Post Method description:
 post(url: string, body: any, options?: RequestOptionsArgs) : Observable

For more details on Angular HTTP: https://angular.io/guide/http

2) If you don't a back-end modules project, and need one

Create a project with Rest APIs that defines your logic to insert data in to your database.
There are many readily available frameworks to create Rest APIs, One such framework using Express.js is Loopback https://v4.loopback.io/getting-started.html. (Knowledge on type script is the only prerequisite to learn this)

Once back-end (web-tier in general terms) project is created, follow the step 1 to insert your data.

There are many other readily available frameworks to create your Rest APIs on different technologies. You can choose one based on your stack.

3) If you don't want a separate back-end project, install Rest API node modules to your angular project, (famous and structured one being express.js) and create Rest APIs to connect to your database. Follow the step 1 to insert your data by invoking these APIs.

4) If you don't want a separate back-end project, and don't want a framework, you can still use plain node.js on which Angular is running, to create Rest APIs. But it might require lot of boiler plate and complex coding.